# Populate a GroupID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID)
INSERT INTO #Test values (1)
INSERT INTO #Test values (2)
INSERT INTO #Test values (3)
INSERT INTO #Test values (0)
INSERT INTO #Test values (4)
INSERT INTO #Test values (5)
INSERT INTO #Test values (6)
INSERT INTO #Test values (8)
INSERT INTO #Test values (12)
INSERT INTO #Test values (19)
INSERT INTO #Test values (0)
INSERT INTO #Test values (44)
```

I am looking for a query that outputs the following (GroupID, ID).

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
2,8
2,12
2,19
3,44
```

A row with an ID of 0 splits the groups.

The query will look something like this:

```
select GroupID = row_number() over (order by (select null)),ID from #Test
```

The GroupID needs to be split using the rows that have a zero value.  The query above just creates a new GroupID for each row.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Do you have some column and/or value that will keep the data in this specific order?  Data isn't ordered without something to specify it so there isn't an easy way to guarantee the zero valued rows in those exact places.

Comment: @TabAlleman Not if you want to split by zero values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, you cannot do what you want with your data structure, because it has no ordering.  However, that is easily fixed by adding an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    TestId int identity(1, 1) primary key,  -- the primary key is not strictly necessary, just my habit with identity columns.
    Val int
);
```

(I took the liberty of renaming your column to `val` instead of `id` to avoid confusion.)  An identity column captures insertion order.

The the group is calculated as the number of zeros before a given value.  In SQL Server 2012+, this is easily done using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum(case when val = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by testid) as groupid
from #test t;
```

I notice that you don't want zeros in the output, for this purpose, use a subquery after the cumulative sum:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             1 + sum(case when val = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by testid) as groupid
      from #test t
     ) t
where val <> 0;
```

Comment: More anonymous downvotes on a correct answer.  This seems to be a pattern today.

Comment: Considering you've been a user for almost 4 years, you really should just ignore downvotes.  Commenting doesn't notify the voter, just shrug them off.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . Cheers.  I appreciate feedback, but find anonymous downvotes irritating (and wish Stack Exchange discouraged them).  Sometimes, I'll go for weeks without downvotes.  Today, I have six (seven if I count a reversal) downvotes on three questions, all without explanation, and all unclear (to me) why.  This is simply an observation.

Comment: I get that they are irritating, everyone hates them but we make them anonymous for many, many reasons.  I would simply _try_ to shrug them off.